# Generating hundreds of css clases

Tags: javascript, css, html5

I have elements that are generated dynamically on the screen. I have bars and diamonds.

[image]

The problem is I have hundreds of different types of bars or diamonds that need to be rendered on the screen. The bars and diamonds are tasks and milestones on a gantt chart. There are hundreds of different types and each type has to have a certain image attached to it for the background so they can be identified a little more easily.

Instead of writing a huge `css` file with `background-image` style I thought it would be  better to dynamically generate a `css` class with the `background-image: url("~/relativepath/imageName")` style.

Each one of these different types of elements have their own image file associated with them. Every element also has a `Code` property such as `EX0blue`. I was thinking of changing the image file names to match the code property, so when the css is generated I can give it a class name of the code and a relative path such as `background-image: url("~/relativepath/code.jpg")`

Is there a more optimal solution than what I am trying to implement?

Here is what I have so far

```
class CssGenerator {

    constructor() {
        this.relativeImagePath = '~/Content/images/activityTypes/';
    }


    createImageClass(code) {

        let style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.innerHTML = '.' + code +' { background-image: url(' + relativeImagePath + code + '.jpg); }';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    }

}
```

Then after that I would add the class like this

```
gantt.templates.task_class=function(start, end, task){
 this.cssGenerator.createImageClass(task.code)
return task.code;
};
```

That return statement applies the string returned as a classname to the dynamic element. It's from the API

Comment: Performance-wise, using canvas/svg might be a better idea.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, performance is actually really important here.

Comment: It might be simpler just to set the `style` property on each element rather than creating a separate stylesheet for each one.

Comment: One more thought, this might be a good option for a library like D3. I also don't think that you can use a tilde in a CSS Url.

Comment: You might want to discuss what these bars and diamonds are, what they do, and why there's a hundred of them rather than your approach. This post reeks of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/177538). There might be better ways to do this, but first we need to know what you are doing and why.

Comment: @josephtheDreamer The bars and diamonds are tasks and milestones on a gantt chart. There are hundreds of different types and each type has to have a certain image attached to it for the background so they can be identified a little more easily.

Comment: @MarcRohloff I don't think D3 would cut it, it's a little too basic for the time I have to build this. Your're right thanks for that about not creating a stylesheet for each element.

Comment: I would echo comment above about investigating SVG and a JavaScript manipulation library like D3 for this. Trying to treat these as images seems a fool's errand.

Comment: At any rate, regardless as to SVG, canvas, CSS3 styling, or whatever libraries you use, this seems to be a vector use case, not a raster one, so consider ditching the idea of raster images in this solution.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. This was a really big help.